Some required attributes are not validated while using form and javascript
I'm using a form for issues with mandatory fields but some aren't taken into account.
Of the 6 required input blocks only 4 are correctly validated when you try to submit the form. The 'IVR status' and the 'Description' blocks are not validated.
I'm drawing a blank what I have missed in the code that exclude these blocks from being validated.


function generateEmail(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var emailTo      = "a@b.c";
  var emailCC      = "d@b.c";
  var emailBCC     = "e@b.c";
  var emailSubject = "WEBFORM: " + $("#subject").val();
  var emailBody    = "Reporter: " + $("#reporter").val() + "%0A%0AThe issue occured on: " + $("#issueDT").val() +
    "%0A%0ACustomer Account Data: " + "%0A   Account: " + $("#accnt_1").val() + "%0A%0ACustomer Account Data: " + "%0A   Account: " + $("#accnt_2").val() + "%0A   Agreement: " + $("#agree_1").val() + "%0A   Agreement: " + $("#agree_2").val() + "%0A   Agreement: " + $("#agree_3").val() + "%0A%0AIVR Status: " + $("#ivrState").val() + "%0A%0ADescription: " + $("#descript").val()
  location.href = "mailto:" + emailTo + "?"
                + ( emailCC      ? "cc="       + emailCC : "") 
                + ( emailBCC     ? "&bcc="     + emailBCC : "") 
                + ( emailSubject ? "&subject=" + emailSubject : "") 
                + ( emailBody    ? "&body="    + emailBody : "");
}

function reloadPage() {
  location.reload();
}
.container {
  width: 800px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}

.control {
  color: blue;
}

h1 {
  color: green;
}

h2 {
  color: red;
}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Report your issue</h1>
  </br>
  </br>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form method="post" class="info" onsubmit="generateEmail(event)">
    Email Subject: </br><input name="subject" placeholder="Subject 20 characters min" id="subject" type="text" size="100" minlength="20" required /></br>
    Reporter Name: </br><input name="reporter" placeholder="Reporter name" id="reporter" type="text" size="100" maxlength="75" required /></br>
    Date & time the issue occured: </br><input name="issueDT" id="issueDT" type="datetime-local" required /></br>
    <label for="ivrState">IVR Status"</label>
    <select name="ivrState" id="ivrStatus" required>
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select</option>
      <option value="fail">Failed</option>
      <option value="pass">Passed</option>
    </select>
    </br>
    </br>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Customer Account Details:</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Account Nr:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="accnt_1" placeholder="Account Info" id="accnt_1" required /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Agreement nr:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="agree_1" placeholder="Agreement Info" id="agree_1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Account Nr:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="accnt_2" placeholder="Account Info" id="accnt_2" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Agreement nr:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="agree_1" placeholder="Agreement Info" id="agree_2" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Agreement nr:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="agree_3" placeholder="Agreement Info" id="agree_3" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </br>
    Give a description: </br> <textarea rows="7" cols="100" minlength="50" id="descript" name="Description" required>Provide a description of min 50 characters.</textarea></br>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="reloadPage()" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="Generate email" onclick="generateEmail()" />
  </form>
</div>




@j08691 it's in the body

That <textarea> has "Provide a description of min 50 characters." in it that counts as valid text as far as I can tell.

This is unrelated to your question, but a reminder that table elements should not be used for page layout. The code in your question is an improper use of tables in HTML.

The select is being marked as valid because the default option has no value attribute. Therefore its value comes from the text contained within the selected option, which is 'Select'. Therefore it's considered to have a value and is valid.
To fix this, add value="" to the default option:
<select name="ivrState" id="ivrStatus" required>
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option value="fail">Failed</option>
  <option value="pass">Passed</option>
</select>

For the textarea, the minlength attribute is only evaluated when the element has been interacted with by the user (more info on that here). Therefore given the initial state of your page the only validation it has to pass is required, which it does due to your default text. To fix this, move the character limit guidance text to the field's label.
Your code can also be improved by:

Avoiding using <br /> elements and &nbsp; for spacing. Use CSS to align things properly, as well as using grouping elements such as label. Also it's <br />, not </br>
Use addEventListener() in JS to bind event handlers, not onclick attributes in JS.
Bind to the submit event of the form, not the click of the submit button, to handle the email generation.
Use string interpolation to build complex strings where you have to. String concatenation gets ugly, quickly.
Don't use table elements for layout. I'll leave this as an exercise for you to fix
If you need to use jQuery, reference it in the <head> of your page, or just before </body>. Do not put it at the start of the <body>

Here's working example with all those adjustments applied.


const form = document.querySelector('form.info');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const emailTo = "a@b.c";
  const emailCC = "d@b.c";
  const emailBCC = "e@b.c";
  const emailSubject = `WEBFORM: ${$("#subject").val()}`;
  const emailBody = `
    Reporter: ${$("#reporter").val()}%0A%0A
    The issue occured on: ${$("#issueDT").val()}%0A%0A
    Customer Account Data: %0A   
    Account: ${$("#accnt_1").val()}%0A%0A
    Customer Account Data: %0A   
    Account: ${$("#accnt_2").val()}%0A   
    Agreement: ${$("#agree_1").val()}%0A
    Agreement: ${$("#agree_2").val()}%0A   
    Agreement: ${$("#agree_3").val()}%0A%0A
    IVR Status: ${$("#ivrState").val()}%0A%0A
    Description: ${$("#descript").val()}`
  location.href = "mailto:" + emailTo + "?" +
    (emailCC ? "cc=" + emailCC : "") +
    (emailBCC ? "&bcc=" + emailBCC : "") +
    (emailSubject ? "&subject=" + emailSubject : "") +
    (emailBody ? "&body=" + emailBody : "");
});

const resetButton = document.querySelector('#resetButton');
resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.location.reload();
});
h1 {
  color: green;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

h2 {
  color: red;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label span {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

label span,
label input {
  display: block;
}

table {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}

.control {
  color: blue;
}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Report your issue</h1>
  <form method="post" class="info">
    <label>
      <span>Email Subject:</span>
      <input name="subject" placeholder="Subject 20 characters min" id="subject" type="text" size="100" minlength="20" required />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Reporter Name:</span>
      <input name="reporter" placeholder="Reporter name" id="reporter" type="text" size="100" maxlength="75" required />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Date &amp; time the issue occured:</span>
      <input name="issueDT" id="issueDT" type="datetime-local" required />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>IVR Status</span>
      <select name="ivrState" id="ivrStatus" required>
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Select</option>
        <option value="fail">Failed</option>
        <option value="pass">Passed</option>
      </select>    
    </label>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Customer Account Details:</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Account Nr:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="accnt_1" placeholder="Account Info" id="accnt_1" required /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Agreement nr:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="agree_1" placeholder="Agreement Info" id="agree_1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Account Nr:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="accnt_2" placeholder="Account Info" id="accnt_2" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Agreement nr:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="agree_1" placeholder="Agreement Info" id="agree_2" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Agreement nr:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="agree_3" placeholder="Agreement Info" id="agree_3" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <label>
      <span>Give a description (min 50 chars): </span>
      <textarea rows="7" cols="100" minlength="50" id="descript" name="Description" required></textarea>
    </label>

    <button type="button" id="resetButton">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit">Generate email</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Wow, only thing I can say here is thank you for educating me, it has been a while I did do HTML/CCS and Java Sripting so need to brush up my coding skills.

No problem, glad to help

Hi Rory, unfortunately when I added the code in my environment I get a 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed error. It doesn't open the email either

I'm unable to replicate that behaviour as the code above seems to work as expected in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/ebmnwxud/. I'd suggest you open devtool and check for errors, and if you find any perhaps start a new question about them if you're unable to debug the problem.

When running Edge Console I get the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at test2.html:53:22)
Does that relate to Line 53 position 22?
as that in the page is this line of code:
const emailBody = ' though the single quote looks like ` no idea what this is

The ` character is a Template Literal and is supported by Edge. By all means return that line of code back to the original to test, but Edge does support Templates, so odd why it would error there.

I've corrected the Template Literal characters and the next error I get is on the add event addEventListener just after the opening {
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

The 405 error on the generate button happens when I click the button and the reset button doesn't work either.
Both issues appear across Edge, Chrome and FireFox
